# shell: how to make tail of a file running in background

Tags: shell, tail

I want to run a few tasks in shell.

1. tail a file into a new file: for example: `tail -f debug|tee -a test.log`
2. at the same time, run other tasks.

My question is: how to make the command `tail -f debug|tee -a test.log` run in background, so that I can run other tasks then in shell script?

Comment: Usually, it is easiest to use a second window/terminal.  Typing commands while log output is also going to the screen is a frustrating experience, in my experience.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, thanks for your advice. Yes, I think it is really a frustrating experience to type command while log output in the same screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need tee at all for this, just use the shell's built-in append operator:

```
tail -f debug >> test.log &
```

The trailing & works as normal in the shell.  You only need tee to send the output to a file as well as standard out, which if you have it in the background probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The difference between this and the code using `tee` is that this does not send the debug output to the terminal - it only sends it to the file.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, thanks for the response, I am much clear about it.

Comment: but how to stop the tail that run in backgroud?

Comment: to kill the background `tail` process, use `kill %tail`

Answer (score 5):

Normally you just use an ampersand after the command if you want to background something.

```
tail -f debug|tee -a test.log &
```

Then you can bring it back to the foreground later by typing `fg`. Did this answer your question or have I missed what you were asking?

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do this is:

```
screen -R -D
tail -f debug|tee -a test.log
Ctrl-A c
ps ax |grep tail
Ctrl-A [Backspace]
...
Ctrl-A [Spacebar]
```

`screen` lets you run multiple terminal sessions on one terminal connection. You switch back and forth with Ctrl-A [Backspace]|[Space]. To create another separate shell Ctrl-A c

A major benefit of screen is that if the terminal session disconnects, it keeps everything runnning. Just close the terminal window or disconnect ssh, go to another computer, log in and run `screen -R -D` to reconnect to everything which is still running.

If you only occasionally need this, just run tail, type Ctrl-Z, run a command, then `fg %1` to bring the tail process back into the foreground, or `bg %1` to make it run in the background permanently. If you do use Ctrl-Z, then the `jobs` command shows all of your detached jobs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can see the running tails with the command 'jobs'. For example:

```
[root@OS4 tufin-admin]# tail -F /var/log/to.log > /tmp/to &
[3] 674697
[root@OS4 tufin-admin]# jobs -pl
[1]  650033 Running                 kubectl logs -f -l app=rma > /tmp/rma &
[2]- 674286 Running                 tail -F var/log/journal/d1524a98a19d4ab59b9ccf9749e3d595/system@d439ce74822b4836ab58a88b6a65d200-0000000000014a12-00060d1140dd3307.journal > /tmp/journal &
[3]+ 674697 Running                 tail -F /var/log/to.log > /tmp/to &
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).